# If $A\in M_{n\times n}^{\mathbb{C}}$ and $T(X)=AX$ for all $X\in M_{n\times \:n}^{\mathbb{C}}$ then $T$ is normal iff $A$ is normal

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My try:
$\underline{\Rightarrow :}$ Assume $T$ is a normal linear transformation.

Therefore there exists a basis $B=\left\{X_1,...,X_n\right\}$
 for $M_{n\times \:n}^{\mathbb{C}}$  that contains eigenvectors of $T$.

Assuming $\lambda _j$ is an egienvalue of the egienvector $X_j$ then

$\lambda _jX_j=T(X_j)=AX_j$

Therefore  $\lambda _j$ is an eigenvalue of A and $X_j$ is the corresponding egienvector of the eigenvalue  $\lambda _j$  . So we can conclude A has $n$ eigenvectors that form a basis for  $M_{n\times \:n}^{\mathbb{C}}$ and therefore A is normal.

the other direction can be showed in a similar manner.
In the proof I relied on a theorem that say: If $V$ is a finite vector space and $T:V \to V$ is a linear transformation over $\mathbb{C}$  then $T$ is normal iff there exists an orthonormal  basis for $V$ that contains eigenvectors of $T$...

The same goes for A.

I Would like to know what you think about my proof please.

Comment: You seem to think that "normal" means "diagonalizable", but "normal" is more. It means that $A^*A = AA^*$. Hence, the question arises which scalar product is used on $M_{n\times n}^{\mathbb C}$ to define the adjoint $T^*$. I guess it's $\langle X,Y\rangle := \operatorname{Tr}(XY^*)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use the scalar product $(X,Y) := \operatorname{Tr}(XY^*)$ on $M_{n\times n}^{\mathbb C}$. Then
$$
(T(X),Y) = (AX,Y) = \operatorname{Tr}(AXY^*) = \operatorname{Tr}(XY^*A) = \operatorname{Tr}(X(A^*Y)^*) = (X,A^*Y).
$$
Hence, $T^*(Y) = A^*Y$. Now it is really simple to show that $T^*T = TT^*$ is equivalent to $A^*A = AA^*$.